# jquery ajax is not passing data properly in this situation

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am creating one website in php. and i am using jquery ajax to pass data from one page to another.
and that is general process for all pages.

my javascript function is :

```
function add_data()
{       
  var searchinOn = mainObjectAddForm['available_add_fields'].split(","); 
  var whereOn="{";
  var where = "";
  for (i=0;i<searchinOn.length;i++)
  {
    var keyValue= searchinOn[i];
    where+=getAddData(mainObjectAddForm[keyValue]['name'],mainObjectAddForm[keyValue]['text'],mainObjectAddForm[keyValue]['datatype'],mainObjectAddForm[keyValue]['data'],keyValue)  

  }  

  whereOn+= where.substring(0,where.length-1)+"}";

  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    data:whereOn,
    url:siteurl + "add/",
     dataType:'json',
    success:function(data)
    {
    }
  });
 }



 function getAddData(name,text,datatype,data,keyValue)
 {  

 var control="";
 var value1="";
 var value2="";
switch(datatype)
{
    case "text":                         
        control +=  "'"+name+"':'"+trim($('#add_form #'+name).val())+"'";
        break;
    case "password":
        control +=  "'"+name+"':'"+trim($('#add_form #'+name).val())+"'";           
        break;      
    case "label":
        control +=  "'"+name+"':'"+trim($('#add_form #'+name).val())+"'";           
        break;          
    case "textarea":
        control +=  "'"+name+"':'"+trim($('#add_form #'+name).val())+"'";           
        break;
}
if (trim(control)=="") return "";
else return control + ",";
}
```

but on php page i am not getting all values. Its coming as one string in post variable.

like

```
 [{'field1':'abc','field2':'pqr','field3':'xyz'}] =>
```

but i want like this :

```
Array
{
[field1] => abc
[field2] => pqr
[field3] => xyz
}
```

and i know the problem that the problem is the ajax data is passing as one string because the '{' and '}' are in whereOn string.
but if i add that in ajax call than also its same problem.

can anyone help me to solve it ?

Comment: It just looks like you need to `json_decode` that...

Comment: On ajax success, the `data` is returned into `json` format. Use php's `json_decode` to decode it.

Comment: means to do json_decode($_POST) ?

Comment: its not working with json_decode either. because my post is in this format : [{'field1':'abc','field2':'pqr','field3':'xyz'}] =>

Answer (score 2):

A couple of suggestions:

1. ***NEVER*** EVER build a JSON by hand. You have a nice good `JSON.stringify(..)` function that all modern browsers support.
2. You are sending a raw JSON in the POST body. Why not set the header `Content-Type: application/json` ?
3. The POST body is **NOT** percentile-encoded. So it does not make sense to use `$_POST` array. What you have to do is read through the entire POST body using `file_get_contents('php://input')` to get the JSON-String. Then you can use `json_decode(..)` to convert that to a PHP object which can be used in the usual way.

   ```
   $postBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
   var_dump($postBody);
   $jsonObj = json_decode($postBody);
   var_dump(jsonObj);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to build json by hand have a look at http://json.org. I'd suggest against that, and using json for that matter.
Instead use application/x-www-form-urlencoded (key/value pairs)

```
function add_data()
{       
  var searchinOn = mainObjectAddForm['available_add_fields'].split(","); 
  var whereOn={};
  var where = "";
  for (i=0;i<searchinOn.length;i++)
  {
    var keyValue= searchinOn[i];
    getAddData(mainObjectAddForm[keyValue]['name'],mainObjectAddForm[keyValue]['text'],mainObjectAddForm[keyValue]['datatype'],mainObjectAddForm[keyValue]['data'],keyValue,whereOn)  

  }  

  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    data:whereOn,
    url:siteurl + "add/",
     dataType:'json',
    success:function(data)
    {
    }
  });
 }



function getAddData(name,text,datatype,data,keyValue,whereOn)
{  
 switch(datatype)
 {
    case "text":                         
        whereOn[name] = trim($('#add_form #'+name).val());
        break;
    case "password":
        whereOn[name] = trim($('#add_form #'+name).val());           
        break;      
    case "label":
        whereOn[name] = trim($('#add_form #'+name).val());           
        break;          
    case "textarea":
        whereOn[name] = trim($('#add_form #'+name).val());           
        break;
 }

}
```

Comment: Hi Musa.. I tried it but its sending data as object so how can i use it in php page ?

Comment: @Mausami `$_POST['field1']`,`$_POST['field2']`,etc

Comment: No its not working. Its giving error msg that <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: field1